# Wild card SSL certificate - redirect http to https

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I have a single HTTPS virtual host for all of my websites. I am trying to redirect subsite2.server.co.uk from http to https.

Here is my HTTPS virtual host (I have shortened it for brevity):

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>   
    ServerName *.server.co.uk  
    ServerAdmin imran.azad@server.co.uk

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.subsite1.server.co.uk$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:8080/VirtualHostBase/https
    /www.subsite1.co.uk:443/Plone/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [L,P]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subsite2.server.co.uk$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subsite2.server.co.uk/$1 [P]
```

Here is my HTTP virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subsite2.server.co.uk
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    Alias /static-dir/ x:/.....
    <Directory x:/.....>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    WSGIScriptAlias / x:/......
    <Directory  x:/......>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I am using the following rewrite condition and rule to do the redirection:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

However the problem I'm having is that it appears as though the server is in a redirect loop. How can I get around this problem?

Here is an error from firefox:

```
The page isn't redirecting properly
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mine is working using something similar, my guess is, try using your regex match instead REQUEST_URI

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =myhost.com
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule /(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Also, could you install live http headers plugin (tools / live http headers), and provide the whole request (with redirections)  traces ?